# Single Writer per partition to get exactly one semantics in Kafka producer side

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

To get exactly once semantics in producer side, Kafka is suggesting to have 1.Use a `single-writer per partition` and every time you get a network error check the last message in that partition to see if your last write succeeded.

Using `Partition key` and Custom Partition Implementation we can specify the destination partition of the message.

Is both are same or different, if different how to check the last write was succeeded or not? Is it something i need to do it with HW in every partition?

Answer (score 0):

'Single writer' means having only one process that writes to the specific kafka partition/partitions. It's quite challenging to support 'exactly once delivery' with 'single writer', high availability, scalability and high performance. I wouldn't recommend to go this way with kafka. I would chose different technology. BTW they have plan to implement exactly once delivery - you can also wait.

I see the implementation by the following way:

1. proxy level
   You decide which application(shard) is responsible for handling the message.
   You can have your own business logic how to divide by shards.
   You probably need here some 'service discovery' to handle which shard is responsible for message(it can be zookeeper). 
   Also you need provide some retry strategy in case of failure.
2. shard level
   It's responsible for writing to a specific kafka partitions. You need to guarantee that only one process is responsible for a specific partition. 
   So you need here some centralized locking(e.g. zookeeper). 
   If shard goes down another node can acquire lock and start handling writes(you need to update service discovery). After acquiring lock you can safely read latest messages and compare if it has been written or not.